# How do I fill a combo box bases on other combo boxes

Tags: c#, combobox, filtering

I have a class that creates a bunch(30) of hex and text strings for commands to be sent to a device.   All the commands use similar parameters.  Here are a few examples.

`public string TmclRotateRight(bool bin, string address, int motor, int value)
public string TmclRotateLeft(bool bin, string address, int motor, int value)
public string TmclStoreGlobalParameter(bool bin, string address, string type, int motor)
public string TmclSetCoordinate(bool bin, string address, string type, int motor, int value)`

I'm building the UI with combo-boxes for the commands and parameters.  Basically I want the user to select the first combo-box, the command, and the other combo-boxes are then populated with the appropriate parameters for that command. Most of the parameters only have a few options except for value which can be just about anything.

What's the best way to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Comment: forgot to say this in windows form not web forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to go is to use databound comboboxes. You can set any enumerable type (e.g. `Array` or `List`) as the other `ComboBox`'s `DataSource` property during the `SelectedIndexChanged` event of your command `ComboBox`.

You can pack all of the comboboxes' `SelectedItem` properties into an `Object` array and use this as the parameters to call your mehtods via reflection.

In case of your `value` parameter, I would suggest using a `TextBox` or `NumericUpDown` to allow arbitrary numeric input.